# Output a single row in pandas to an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I would like to be able to pull out an arbitrary row, such as the 4th row, and get an array so that I can send it through another function.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Pandas data is stored internally as Numpy arrays, you can extract the Numpy representation directly.

#### v0.24+

Use [`pd.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) method:

```
df.iloc[3].to_numpy()  # output 4th row as Numpy array
```

#### Before v0.24

Use [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) property:

```
df.iloc[3].values  # output 4th row as Numpy array
```

Just remember that if your dataframe contains multiple types, the `dtype` of the row-wise Numpy array may become `object`. This will lead to inefficiencies in subsequent operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Dummy DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
# Extract second row (index: 1)
df.iloc[1].values
```

Comment: as_matrix was deprecated since version 0.23.0. Generally, it is recommended to use ‘.values’ as shown below in the accepted answer.